# Puppteer image styling off using heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

Using puppeteer locally to take an image of some HTML works as expected, but when pushed to heroku,  parts inside the image are out of alignment.

They both use the same code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
 })
await page.goto(`https://f1-cards.herokuapp.com/team/mercedes`)
await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' })
await browser.close()
```

Locally I use macOS and I believe heroku is ubuntu.

It could be a CSS problem but I'm not sure since other CSS rules appear okay within the same image. Does it make sense that some styles would be ignored by puppeteer and not the entire stylesheet?

This is the image taken locally:
[image: proper image]
And the image taken on heroku:
[image: improper image]

Since heroku respects the CSS when the page is rendered in plain HTML this leads me to believe this must be a puppeteer issue. [Link](https://f1-cards.herokuapp.com/team?team=mercedes) to plain HTML version (page may take some time load - 10+ secs).

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4953) with puppeteer. There are no error messages so debugging help would be welcome.

Comment: "one is mac other is heroku" probably difference is in how chrome renders those pages, notice that resolutions of screenshots are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was the viewport area being too small on ubuntu and pushing the HTML together. Adding a different viewport width in production fixed the issue.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    })
const page = await browser.newPage()
/////// added this
 await page.setViewport({
      width: 1000,
      height: 600,
      deviceScaleFactor: 1
})

await page.goto(`https://f1-cards.herokuapp.com/team/mercedes`)
await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' })
await browser.close()
    await page.goto(`https://f1-cards.herokuapp.com/team/mercedes`)
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' })
    await browser.close()
})
```